# How Virtual Particles "look" and "act" in classical analogies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces, virtual-particles

My question comes in three parts

### **(1.)**

The first has to do with how to visualize the method of virtual particle operation in the context of simpler analogies of classical physics.

I know that may sound vague, so I'll try to elaborate:

Take the case of an electron and proton in a Hydrogen atom. The classical (and technically wrong) analogy of this situation is that the electron follows a circular orbit around the proton, and the orbit is maintained by the attraction of the charges, which acts like a centripetal force. This centripetal force causes the electron and proton to act on each other at all times, so at every point, the electron deviates its path to create the circular path. In other words, the interaction in this situation is continuous and controlled by $F = \frac{kq_1 q_2}{r^2}$

When I try to take this classical analogy and mold it to make use of virtual photons, I imagine this:

As the electron moves, a virtual photon is exchanged, travels to the electron, and informs it to deviate its path. The electron does so and then continues on its path until the next virtual photon exchange. This results in the electron going around the proton, but this time, the circular orbit is more a regular polygon, with a vertex at each point where a virtual photon exchange occurred. So instead of the electron being continuously deviated, its orbit is completed in quantized steps. Is this reasonable to image?

I know this is not how things actually "look", but in the context of this simplistic model for particles and atoms, would this be a valid way to upgrade that model from using continuous "forces" as machinery of interaction to virtual particles?

### **(2.)**

ALSO, how does this work out if the objects in question are far apart? For example, take an electron and proton again. Only this time, they're not bound in an atom, but instead far away from each other. Classically, if they were released from rest, the visualization would be that they start moving toward each other, first slowly, but constantly accelerating because the force between them would grow as distance shrinks. Again, this would result in a continuous ramp up in velocity as they get closer.

If I try to replace forces with virtual particles, this situation starts out the same way, with the particles at rest, but then the electron/proton pair begins to exchange virtual photons, and they both get a kick of velocity each time they receive a new one. Again, this results in the electron/proton accelerating toward each other, but this time in a series of quantized steps.

### **(3.)**

In imagining the scenario from part 2, I got stuck thinking about how a virtual photon could travel so far between charged particles if virtual particles are supposed to be short lived. The way I reconciled this was to use the fact that virtual particles have a shorter life the more energy/mass they have. So a high mass/energy virtual particle is gone very quickly and acts on short distances, but a low mass/energy virtual particle can live longer and travel a greater distance. So when an electron and proton are far apart, they must exchange virtual photons that are low in mass/energy so that they can reach over the large distance. As they electron and proton get close together, they can exchange more energetic/massive virtual photons because they don't need to last as long to make the trip. And this would elegantly fit into how the strength of attraction between charged particles decreases with distance. Is this way of thinking about it worth anything?

Thank you for your time and effort to help!!!

Comment: I strongly encourage you *not* to envision electrons going around in polygons. There is *nothing classical* about virtual particles. They don’t even obey the normal relationship between energy and momentum.

Comment: @G.Smith I would even add they don’t even exist. They are purely a figment of a mathematical method to solve a problem.

Comment: @Oбжорoв I agree with that, but I don’t think Feynman did.

Comment: To understand what the "virtual particle" thing is all about, you don't need classical *analogies*. You can understand it already in straight-up classical physics. The most important thing to understand about virtual particles is that they are not specific to quantum field theory. They also arise in *classical* field theory, for exactly the same reason. This is explained in Helling's "Solving Classical Field Equations" ([link to pdf](https://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~helling/classical_fields.pdf)). It's mathematical, of course. None of this can be properly understood without the math.

Comment: By the way, my comment doesn't contradict @G.Smith's comment. The word "particle" is overloaded. G.Smith's comment uses the word in the most familiar sense. My comment gives a link that explains what the word means when it follows the adjective *virtual*. Virtual particles occur in classical field theory, but they are nothing at all like classical particles. The language is a mess, because physicists don't rely on precise meanings of words. Any ambiguities in the words -- and there are *lots* of them -- are cleared up by math and experiments.